# Javascript Function Array Remove Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have **Javascript** Filter Item Class and array which is like below

```
function FilterItem(filterId, filterType) {
    this.filterId = filterId;
    this.filterType = filterType;
}

var filterItemArray = [];
```

I am adding Filter Items to this array like below

```
function AddFilterItem(filterId, filterType) {
    filterItemArray.push(new FilterItem(filterId, filterType));
}
```

I also need to remove item from this array by specific filterId

```
function RemoveFilterItem(filterId, filterType) {
    var item = new filterItem(filterId, filterType);
    var itemIndex = jQuery.inArray(item, filterItemArray);
}
```

But this does not work and I dont think it is the efficient way? My Question is what is the best way to remove this item in RemoveFilterItem Method

Comment: You could search for it in the array and remove it. In a loop you can examine each element until you find it. What you have now will create another element with the same properties.

Comment: @Rudy yes this is my curreny approach right now, I just want to get item index by duplicated item in this array. I think I should create my own findItemIndex method, this will check each item till found then return item index if exist

Comment: You are creating a new instance, how do you think it would match a different instance?

Comment: Don't create global methods `AddFilterItem` and `RemoveFilterItem`, use `FilterItem.prototype.add` and `FilterItem.prototype.remove`

Comment: So...if this is a big, performance-sensitive collection, and you're often going to be finding elements in it via an ID...would it not make sense to turn it into a map (Or, in JavaScript terms, an Object)? That wouldn't prevent you from looping through the object keys when you just want to do something to each element.

Comment: @JuanMendes I like object-oriented programming, but this operation is being performed on the filterItemArray, not on a FilterItem. Even if you made them "self-removing", you're tying an explicit dependency back to a particular collection (precluding the possibility for multiple collections)

Comment: @Katana314 That was a typo on my part, if you [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30397423/227299), you'll see what I mean, `FilterItems.prototype.remove(id, type)` I definitely agree that using a map may make sense, the problem is that a map doesn't have order and the filters probably do need order... so that's more to think about and code for.

Comment: @JuanMendes Hm...his example doesn't show him having a `FilterItems` type yet, but that could be a good idea so that users of the class don't have to change methods each time this changes. I'd think the best way of maintaining order would be to deploy riot polic-I mean, have an array that only contains filterIds, and iterate through that when accessing sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30396668/227299) works, but you can [make it a **lot** faster](http://jsperf.com/filter-to-remove-items-from-array/2) using [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).  [Manwal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30396757/227299) uses splice but fails if there are duplicate filters.

[image]

I would also use OO code instead of global functions.

```js
function FilterItem(filterId, filterType) {
    this.filterId = filterId;
    this.filterType = filterType;
}

function FilterItems() {
    this.items = [];
}

FilterItems.prototype.add = function (filterId, filterType) {
    this.items.push(new FilterItem(filterId, filterType));
}

FilterItems.prototype.remove = function (filterId, filterType) {
    for (var i = this.items.length - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        var item = this.items[i];
        if (item.filterId === filterId && item.filterType === filterType) {
            this.items.splice(i, 1);
        }    
    }
}

var filters = new FilterItems();
filters.add(1, 1);
filters.add(2, 2);
// Adding two filters of the same type/id to prove that it can remove
// multiple items
filters.add(1, 1);

filters.remove(1, 1);

console.log(filters.items.length);
console.log(filters.items[0]);
```

Comment: Both your's and above Andy's answer works but I think this is the best approach for performance case, I accepted this as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the native `filter` function:

```
function RemoveFilterItem(filterId, filterType) {    
    filterItemArray = filterItemArray.filter(function (el) {
        return el.filterId !== filterId && el.filterType !== filterType;
    });
}
```

This will give you the array without that element with that id and type.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hb07kb4a/)

And here's a modified version of Manwal's answer but without the jQuery again:

```
function RemoveFilterItem(filterId, filterType) {
    for (var i = 0, l = filterItemArray.length; i < l; i++) {
        var el = filterItemArray[i];
        if (el.filterId === filterId && el.filterType === filterType) {
            filterItemArray.splice(i, 1);

            // because we're caching the length of the array
            // we need to adjust the length of l once the splice has taken place
            l--;
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tz609L8s/)

Comment: Upvoted, it's just not very elegant since you have to create a whole new array.

Comment: Doesn't use jQuery tho :)

Comment: @Andy That's definitely a plus, I am working on a jsperf to compare performance of using splice and searching instead

Comment: Add your result as a comment here as I'd like to see that.

Comment: @Andy Splice is waaaaay faster http://jsperf.com/filter-to-remove-items-from-array :) See my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.each` to iterate each element of array and then `splice` it:

```
function RemoveFilterItem(filterId, filterType) {    
    var item = new FilterItem(filterId, filterType);
    $.each(filterItemArray, function( index, value){
        if(value.filterId == item.filterId){
            filterItemArray.splice(index,1);
        }
    });   
}
```

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/qa6gh12p/)

---

No need to create new `FilterItem` while removing:

```
function RemoveFilterItem(filterId, filterType) {    
    $.each(filterItemArray, function( index, value){
        if(value.filterId === filterId && value.filterType === filterType){
            filterItemArray.splice(index,1);
        }
    });   
}
```

[**See Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qa6gh12p/1/)

Comment: Why are you creating a new `FilterItem` just to delete it?

Comment: @JuanMendes added modified solution also.

Comment: This will fail if there are two items with the same id/type because you're modifying the array and the index is shifting, you can fix that by looping backwards.

Comment: I can understand this will fail on this situation. if i shall use `$.each(filterItemArray.reverse(), function(i, v)` this condition can happen also. What do you think?

Comment: No it wouldn't, you have to loop backwards, not just reverse the array, because if you still loop forward, it will shift the index of the items you haven't seen yet